# Predicting in a Bayesian Network in R -- message: consider using the 'smooth' argument

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I've gotten code figured out to predict probabilities in each category of the target node.  However, when I try to adapt it to a different dataset (just more nodes of similar type data), when I try run the predict function, it gives this message (in black text, not red like an error or warning):

> The evidence for row 25 has probability smaller than 0.00000 in then
>   model. Consider using the 'smooth' argument when building the network.
>   Exiting...

Here is the code:

```
library("bnlearn")
pigment.test <- read.table("pigment_test.csv", sep=",", header=T)
bn.mle <- bn.fit(dg_pigment, data=pigment.test[,2:19], method="mle", smooth=0.01)
bn.grain <- as.grain(bn.mle)
predict.mle <- predict(bn.grain, "pigment", newdata=pigment_val[,2:18], 
                       type="distribution")
predict.mle
```

I tried putting `smooth` in the `bn.fit` or the `as.grain` part of the code, but it says its an unused argument.  This happens for other rows (not just 25 when I remove it). Does anyone know where I could include a `smooth` argument here?  Or is there a different function?  I was trying to have the program automatically calculate the conditional probabilities rather than me manually creating the tables.

Comment: The `grain()` function has a `smooth` argument

Comment: When I try adding smooth to the grain function above though, it says its an unused argument.  And what do you set it equal to? I've seen 'e' , but I don't know what that means

Comment: not in `as.grain`, function `grain` (from package `grain`); smooth=0.01-0.1

Comment: how could I fit that into the code above so I still get to use the predict() function?

Comment: I tried to `compile` the `as.grain` network and add the `smooth`, but it changes the arcs in the model and still gives the same message.  Is there another way to go about this?